# convert c# to javascript here. - javascript change string to array

Tags: javascript, c#

how would I convert this c# code to javascript to accomplish the same thing.

```
var s = styles.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `styles` is a string, it's as simple as:

```
styles.split(/[\r|\r\n]/);
```

```js
var styles = 'body {font-size: 12px;}\n\
.someClass {color: red}';

document.querySelector('#result').textContent = '[' + (styles.split(/[\r|\r\n]/)) +']';
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I am trying to split the array at the comma.  this didn't seem to work.

Comment: i am trying to change this:                  var s = style.split(/\r\n|\r/);
        return manager.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from("Orders").where("ID", "==", style));

Comment: The result of `split` *is* an `Array`. You can't split an `Array`, you *can* split a String. I can't say much on your usage of the splitted String `style`, but it seems wrong to use an `Array` as selector within a query. You can use *elements* from an `Array` though: `s[element.position]`, e.g. `s[0]` returns the first element of array `s`.